# Forms of Latin in Choral Music

Tags: choral

I was always taught that the choice of Germanic or Italianate Latin is determined by the nationality of the composer.  The exception would be composers AFTER the pope's letter on CHURCH LATIN  (Italianate).

What is the consensus of conductors?

Comment: There is no consensus.  It is a very controversial question.

Comment: I rather doubt many conductors give a rat's patootie as to what some pope wrote.  Beside that, you might consider that operas are very often sung in the language of the country where they're being performed rather than the original language.  Pronunciation can be handled similarly.

Comment: And because I can't resist -- how about Pig Latin?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance of Latin, but what does it matter what the conductor thinks? It seems to me all that matters is what the composer wrote, unless this is a question of pronunciation.

Comment: @Richard i believe the question *is* entirely one of pronunciation.

Comment: As phoog says, this is not a simple matter.  If you're interested in how Latin was (presumably) pronounced at the time and place of different compositions, the classic work is Copeman:  https://www.amazon.com/Singing-Pronunciation-explord-Harold-Copeman/dp/0951579800